# Alternative to Loop over columns in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = np.random.randint(low=-2, high=10, size=(100,21))
df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[['A'] + [f"{col}_{i}" for col in list("BCDEF") for i in range(4)]])
print(df.head())

A B_0 B_1 B_2 B_3 C_0 C_1 C_2 C_3  ... D_3 E_0 E_1 E_2 E_3 F_0 F_1 F_2 F_3 F_4
0  5  -1   8   1   7   5   2   8   8  ...   2   6   0   2   8   1   2   7   6
1  3   5   1   2   6   8   7  -1   3  ...   3   2   0   8  -2   8  -2   5   7
2  1   8  -2  -2   7  -1   8   6   5  ...   4  -1   7   5   4   7   6   7   1
3  0   9   9  -1   4   2   4   5   3  ...   3   4   6   3   1   2   5   6   6
4  8   1   3   2   0   2   9  -1   7  ...   5   8   2   5   2   4  -1   0  -1
```

My target is to perform data calculation over my columns so that the calculation starts from the columns with small indices and moves towards the columns with bigger indices:

```
for i in range(4):
    condition = i - df['A'] > 0
    if i > 0:
        df.loc[condition, f'B_{i}'] = df[f"B_{i-1}"] * 2.5 + df[f"C_{i-1}"] * 5 + df[f"D_{i-1}"] * 1.5
        df.loc[condition, f'C_{i}'] = df[f"B_{i - 1}"] * 2.5 + df[f"C_{i - 1}"] * 5 + df[f"D_{i - 1}"] * 1
        df.loc[condition, f'D_{i}'] = df[f"B_{i - 1}"] * 2.5 + df[f"C_{i - 1}"] * 5 + df[f"D_{i - 1}"] * 1

    condition = i - df['A'] >= 0
    df.loc[condition, f'E_{i}'] = df[f"B_{i-1}"] * 1.2 + df[f"C_{i-1}"] * 1.4 + df[f"D_{i-1}"] * 1.6
    ....
```

The calculation of column i is dependent from the columns i-1. In my example, I am multiplying the columns by constant values. However, in the real example, they are multiplied by other constant columns in the dataframe. On every iteration, some of the dataframe columns are updated.

**What would be the best way to optimize this process? Would it be possible to vectorize this process if the result of iteration i + 1 depends on the result of iteration i ?**

Comment: can you provide a more minimal input example and the matching expected output?

Comment: My actual dataframe contains 370 columns, so it is a bit complicated to share parts of it but it is 95% to what I have shared. Just instead of the constant values I have provided, you also have other columns indexed from 0 to 24 that will also be included in the for loop ex `df.loc[condition, f'B_{i}'] = df[f"B_{i-1}"] * df[f"CB_{i-1}"] + df[f"C_{i-1}"] * df[f"CC_{i-1}"] + df[f"D_{i-1}"] * df[f"CD_{i-1}"]` (and my actual loop in my current code spans from 0 to 24). My target is to optimize this part as much as possible (current process time between 2.5 to 3 seconds).

Comment: I don't understand your problem exactly, but to speed up calculations you could use numpy arrays instead of a dataframe.